# How do one access the struct of its derived class c++

Tags: c++, oop

**Question**

Wondering if there is any method or "clever" class design we could use to access struct fields of the derived class while iterating through a vector containing pointers of the base class,

**Introduction**

My example classes are as follow:

```
 struct Detail{
     int allegic_food_item;
 };

class Client{
  public:
      Client();
      virtual void ~Client();
};

class VIP: public Client{
  public:
       VIP(int x);
       struct Detail details;
       int getPayment();
  private:
       int id;
 };
```

Suppose that VIP instances that are created is pushed into a client list

```
 std::vector<Client* >clientList;
 clientList.push_back(new VIP(int x));
```

Now, if we have a requirement to create a menu class which has list of food item in menu to search through the client list to find the particular vip that is allergy to the particular food item

**What I have done**
I am thinking of creating a member function getAllergy for both Client and VIP. The implementation is somewhat as below

```
class Client{
  public:
      Client();
      virtual void ~Client();

     virtual int getAllergy();
};

class VIP: public Client{
  public:
       VIP(int x);
       virtual void ~VIP();

       struct Detail details;
       int getPayment();

       int getAllergy(){ 
          return details.allegic_food_item 
       };
  private:
       int id;
 };  


  getVIPAllergy(std::vector<Client *> clientList_ptr, int ingredients_num)
  {
     auto func = std::find_if(clientList_ptr.begin(), clientList_ptr.end(), [this](auto const &client) { return client->getAllergy() == ingredients_num }

    return *func;

  }
```

But I am wondering whether there is another way I could achieve above, for there is further requirement to get different pieces of information from the detail struct

Regards

Comment: Nope, this is exactly what virtual function are used for, so the shown approach is the right one. For most common definitions of "right", and taking into account that the obvious typos, above, mean that the shown code isn't real code, and only demoes the basic concept.

Comment: Either make a base class function available as you did or dynamic cast when iterating. Both have advantages (e.g. safety) and disadvantages (e.g. base class functions only applicable to certain derived classes). The book 'Pattern Hatching: Design Patterns Applied' describes a filesystem with the composite pattern and it has the same dilemma. Directories and files have similar and distinct properties and how to deal with this.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is a red flag, you resort to it when your design is broken and you do not have or want to spend the resources to refactor.

Comment: Minor point: destructors (and constructors) don't have a return type. Change `virtual void ~Client();` to `virtual ~Client();` and `virtual void ~VIP();` to `virtual ~VIP();` (although the `virtual` in `~VIP` is redundant).

Comment: Another minor point: you don't need `struct` in `struct Detail details;`; `Detail details;` is sufficient. In C `struct` is needed; in C++ it's not.

Comment: @spectras: not a red flag at all. If I use Vlissides example of as filesystem it can become pretty messy to put all directory related functionality as base class overriden functions. One can argue about the OOD but it's not abnormal to have a class hierarchy where derived classes have special unrelated properties. His book discusses it in more detail.

Comment: @gast128 there is an entire world outside OO. And while I do agree the approach you mention will become pretty messy, the problem is in using the wrong design. Trying to make up for it by piercing through layers with `dynamic_cast` will only make it worse. Thus the appearance of `dynamic_cast` serving as a red flag for a wrong design.